# Javascript replace() with $1

Tags: javascript

Input string is "thisIsSpinalTap". I replaced each uppercase letter with it's lowercase version. I also wanted to add a - before the letter to get the spinal case effect "this-is-spinal-tap".

I wrote the following line of code:

```
str = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

This replaced each uppercase letter with - to produce "this-s-pinal-ap". This was not the desired effect.

I read that using $1 could produce the effect I wanted, and it did.

```
str = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase();
```

How does the $1 work to append - to the string, rather than replace the uppercase letter?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` is the first group captured in the regular expression.

So in this case, `-$1` will replace what was matched with `-`, followed by the uppercase letter captured in `([A-Z])`.